# Is there a shorthand way to set many object properties?

Tags: php

Because I'm lazy I was wondering if PHP has a shorthand way to set properties like this...

```
with $person_object {
    ->first_name = 'John';
    ->last_name = 'Smith';
    ->email = 'spam_me@this-place.com';
}
```

Is there anything like this? Or, is there a lazy way to set properties without having to type `$person_object` over and over again?

Comment: you could make a generic decorator function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could implement something akin to the builder pattern within your `Person` class. The approach involves returning `$this` at the end of every setter call.

```
$person
    ->set_first_name('John')
    ->set_last_name('Smith')
    ->set_email('spam_me@this-place.com');
```

And in your class...

```
class Person {
    private $first_name;
    ...
    public function set_first_name($first_name) {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        return $this;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a bad hack. Don't Abuse A Pattern To Achieve A Shorthand!

Answer (score 3):

No.

No, there's not.

Answer (score 2):

A generic decorating function could do this for you:

```
function decorate( $object, $data )
{
  foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
  {
    $object->$key = $value;
  }
}

decorate( $person_object, array( 'first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Smith' ) );
```

<sub>I may have made some mistakes, it's been a while since I wrote PHP code, and this is untested</sub>

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so. You could however make such a thing:

```
class Person {

function __call($method, $args) {
    if (substr($method, 0, 3) == set) {
        $var = substr($method, 3, strlen($method)-3);
        $this->$var = $args[0];
    } else {
        //throw exception
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with *arrays* instead of objects, you could technically use [`compact()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) for this, but since it uses strings to look-up the variable names, it's not as foolproof as the way [shorthand property names work in ES2015 JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions). You can cast an array into being a `stdObject` but that's not as useful when you need the object to be of a specific type. There does not appear to be a way to do what you're seeking with objects in PHP because it would break encapsulation; JavaScript, OTOH, exposes all object state publicly.

**Side note:** the docs note that `compact()` is the opposite of [`extract()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) -- which one might consider using to simulate object de-structuring with arrays. However, with `extract()` the incoming array pretty much gets free-reign over the symbol table, so I wouldn't recommend using it; in PHP 7.3 and later, I'd recommend using [array destructuring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.new-features.php#migration73.new-features.core.destruct-reference) instead).